# Sql Server 2008 Web Licensing / Edition Limitations

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, licensing, filestream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

How is Sql Server 2008 Web licensed? When clicking on how to buy on the Microsoft pages it shows only SPLA pricing of $15 per processor per month. Does that mean it's only available from resellers that host it for you?

Since the pricing of it is based per processor does that mean that there is no limitations on the number of users allowed to access the database ie there are no CAL licenses?

Finally, is there any key functionality that is missing from the web edition for a database that all it really does is act as a simple data store for a website? I would at some point like to take advantage of the FileStream functionality that was added to 2008 is that available on the web edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you referring to this page:
 http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/pricing.aspx

It does seem that it's only available through volume licensing or SPLA.  If you're an established organization, then you should be using volume licensing anyways.  You have to have an agreement setup, but it's not difficult to do, get in contact with a reseller.

1. SQL Web Edition is available to through Volume Licensing, & also available for free through Microsoft's [BizSpark program](http://www.microsoft.com/BizSpark/), if you’re a small business.
2. Per processor licenses mean there is no need for CAL's so this is perfect for licensing for a web application.

Apart from the [4CPU](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions.aspx) limitation, there are also a few 2008 features that are not available.  [MSDN has a full list of features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx) that 2008 web edition support, and yes, filestream is supported.

Comment: We don't meet the age or revenue requirements for bizspark.

Comment: What's the best way to get started with the Microsoft Volume Licensing program? Prior to my current job I never had to deal with any of the acquisition stage of software and was always just provided it.

Comment: I haven't done that kind of thing myself for a few years. Find a reseller & contact them. http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Server 2008 does come with FILESTREAM support.

I'm always confused with their complex licensing systems, but I believe web is only available from resellers and doesn't come with CALs or it has a limited amount of CALs and you can't buy more.

You can buy SQL Server 2008 Standard with 10CALs for around 2000 USD and you will own it, and you can take it wherever you want.

My biased advice? Go with MySQL.

Comment: 10 CAL's isn't suitable for a website application